# Подсветка выбранного элемента в компоненте Gallery в ОС Android

Tags: android, java

Здравствуйте. Каким образом можно выделить произвольный выбранный элемент компонента Gallery в Android? Под выделением я имею в виду: подсветка, обвод контуром или ещё как-то. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

`Gallery` наследует от `AbsSpinner`'а, а в `AbsSpinner` есть методы управления выбором `setSelection(int location, boolean animate)` и `setSelection(int location)`

[Читаем доку!](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsSpinner.html#setSelection%28int,%20boolean%29)